# Доклад закончен или окончен?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография, выбор-слов

Правильно говорить "Доклад окончен" или "Доклад закончен"? Мне почему-то кажется, сказать нужно "Доклад окончен".
Сейчас сижу смотрю заседание правительства региона, и министр образования говорит: "Доклад закончен". И меня это почему-то резануло...

Comment: Докладчик может избежать (что б не резало) оба варианта, завершив свою речь глаголом: «Доклад закончил».

Comment: @shampar Почему думаете что "Доклад закончил" режет ухо меньше, чем ""Доклад закончен"? Доклад закончен -> Доклад закончил. Доклад окончен -> Доклад окончил.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, верно и так и так.

> [Закончить и окончить](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?layout=item&id=36_200)
>
> Вопрос
>   Как правильно: закончить работу или окончить работу? Закончить университет или окончить университет?
>
> Глагол закончить в значении «довести до конца, завершить» синонимичен глаголу окончить, правильно: закончить работу и окончить работу.
>
> В значении «пройти какой-либо курс обучения, завершить обучение где-либо» употребляется только глагол окончить: окончить школу, вуз, университет, курсы и т. п.
>
> Правильно
>   Закончить работу и окончить работу, но: окончить школу.

Answer (score 1):

**Мне тоже почему-то кажется, что лучше сказать "доклад окончен", остается только понять почему.**

Мы довольно часто употребляем глаголы *окончить и закончить* в качестве синонимов: окончить и закончить ремонт, окончить и закончить работу, но всё-таки полными синонимами они не являются.

Попробуем сравнить причастия *законченный и оконченный.* Оконченный — форма глагола *окончить*, а вот у причастия *законченный* есть собственная статья в словаре:

ЗАКОНЧЕННЫЙ,  1. Обладающий **целостностью, полнотой; завершённый**. З-ая мысль. 2. **Достигший полноты проявления** свойств, качеств, совершенства в каком-л. деле, искусстве и т.п. З-ое изящество форм и линий. З. образец классической поэмы.

**Завершенность** — вот главное, что характерно для этого слова. Можно окоончить/закончить процесс работы, но пока еще не получить окончательный результат, и в некоторых случаях эти различия становятся существенными.

Мы говорим: **окончить школу**, но речь идет лишь об окончании процесса обучения в образовательной средней школе. А вот сочетание "закончить школу" может претендовать на полноту и завершенность действия, поэтому его не рекомендуется использовать.

Писатель может окончить роман, а критик скажет, что произведение не кажется законченным, совершенным, его надо еще доработать.

**И теперь о докладе.**

Когда министр образования говорит "доклад окончен", это значит, что окончено  чтение  доклада (процесс).  Если мы говорим "доклад закончен, урок закончен", то это можно отнести не к процессу, а к тексту доклада, к материалу урока, в которых **тема раскрыта целиком и полностью.**